# Oracle ManagedDataAccess GetDecimal specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am using EF6 Oracle.ManagedDataAccess v18.3.0, database first concept (edmx). The problem is that Oracle table stores Number that has higher precision (38 digits), that the default Decimal C# data type to which the oracle Number is mapped. Decimal has precision max 28-29 digits. Because of that OracleManagedDataAccess provider throws exeption below:

> at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ShapedBufferedDataRecord.ReadDecimal(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ShapedBufferedDataRecord.Initialize(DbDataReader reader, DbSpatialDataReader spatialDataReader, Type[] columnTypes, Boolean[] nullableColumns)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ShapedBufferedDataRecord.Initialize(String providerManifestToken, DbProviderServices providerServices, DbDataReader reader, Type[] columnTypes, Boolean[] nullableColumns)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.BufferedDataReader.Initialize(String providerManifestToken, DbProviderServices providerServices, Type[] columnTypes, Boolean[] nullableColumns)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__a()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>      at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>      at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
>      at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__0[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>      at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>      at TransakcijskiCertifikatGOTS.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\sl0gas\Desktop\JiraRepo\Proizvodnja\TransportniCertifikatiGOTS\TransakcijskiCertifikatGOTS\TransakcijskiCertifikatGOTS\Program.cs:line 34

**Is there any known workaround to solve this problem? So far I have tried this:**

1. Setting the Precision on specific Member that is causing the problem in edmx file to 28,
2. Changing the App.config to below configuration and trying different options

   ```
     <edmMappings>
   <edmNumberMapping>
     <add NETType="bool" MinPrecision="1" MaxPrecision="1" DBType="Number" />
     <add NETType="int16" MinPrecision="2" MaxPrecision="5" DBType="Number" />
     <add NETType="int32" MinPrecision="6" MaxPrecision="10" DBType="Number" />
     <add NETType="int64" MinPrecision="11" MaxPrecision="19" DBType="Number" />
     <add NETType="Decimal" MinPrecision="20" MaxPrecision="28" DBType="Number" />
     <add NETType="String" MinPrecision="29" MaxPrecision="38" DBType="Number" />
   </edmNumberMapping>
   ```
3. Changing the default cast from Decimal to string so I could then manually convert to Decimal or double, but the provider throws not valid cast exception.

I am using LINQ syntax to query the database!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a function call as well as a table.  For the table column I changed the .NET type to double and handled the conversion - so far I haven't had any precision issues.

My workaround for a function call is as follows:

```
var command = "some_oracle_function(:first_parameter)";

var xx = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(command, firstParameter).SingleOrDefault();
var oracleDecimal = new OracleDecimal(xx);
return oracleDecimal.IsNull ? 0 : OracleDecimal.SetPrecision(oracleDecimal, 28).Value
```

I force the response as a string and generate a new OracleDecimal - this allows the large overflowing decimal number - then i cast it to a handleable size within the .NET framework and return the valid decimal value.  This has worked without issue for me for some time.

Comment: Problem is that I am using Linq queries to get data from database. As I see you use SQL in a string format and then passing it to the ManagedProvider. Of course I could switch to this approach but Linq has some advantages that I need in this case.

Comment: Try using double as column type in .NET

Comment: If I do that then it throws this kind of error "Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type Edm.Double[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=] of member "..." in type "..." is not compatible with OracleEFProcider.number [Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=38,Scale=0]

Answer (score 0):

When exact decimal precision is not a concern, I simply ROUND my number to less digits of precision in the SQL query. This solve my problem. It also makes the display look better.